# list.add seems to be adding a reference to the original object?

Tags: c#, list

I have created a couple custom classes (`NTDropDown` and `NTBaseFreight`) which I use to store data that I retrieve from a DB. I initialize a List of `NTBaseFreight` and 2 lists for `NTDropDown`.

I can successfully use `List.Add` to add freights to the freights list, but as I debug the code, my 2 dropdown lists contain only 1 `NTDropDown`, which always has the same values as `NTDropDown` (I'm assuming this is a referencing problem, but what am I doing wrong)?

To give an example, on the second row, if the carrier and `carrier_label` were `"001", "MyTruckingCompany"` and I put a break on the if statement for `frt_carriers`, both frt_carriers and frt_modes would contain only 1 item in their list, with the values `"001", "MyTruckingCompany"`...the same values in `NTDropDown`.

Code:

```
List<NTDropDown> frt_carriers = new List<NTDropDown>();
List<NTDropDown> frt_modes = new List<NTDropDown>();
List<NTBaseFreight> freights = new List<NTBaseFreight>();
NTDropDown tempDropDown = new NTDropDown();
NTBaseFreight tempFreight = new NTBaseFreight();

//....Code to grab data from the DB...removed

while (myReader.Read())
{
    tempFreight = readBaseFreight((IDataRecord)myReader);

    //check if the carrier and mode are in the dropdown list (add them if not)
    tempDropDown.value = tempFreight.carrier;
    tempDropDown.label = tempFreight.carrier_label;
    if (!frt_carriers.Contains(tempDropDown)) frt_carriers.Add(tempDropDown);

    tempDropDown.value = tempFreight.mode;
    tempDropDown.label = tempFreight.mode_label;
    if (!frt_modes.Contains(tempDropDown)) frt_modes.Add(tempDropDown);

    //Add the freight to the list
    freights.Add(tempFreight);
}
```

Comment: ok, i figured it out...I need to initialize a NEW NTDropDown each time (not re-use tempDropDown over and over again). so, adding `tempDropDown = new NTDropDrop();` before I use it each time. Should I delete this question?

Comment: No. Leave the question up. Solving your own question is still useful to everyone.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, a list of reference types is actually just a list of references.

You have to create a new instance for each object that you want to store in the list.

Also, the `Contains` method compares references, so two objects containing the same data are not considered to be equal. Look for a value in the properties of the objects in the list.

```
if (!frt_carriers.Any(c => c.label == tempFreight.carrier_label)) {
  NTDropDown tempDropDown = new NTDropDown {
    value = tempFreight.carrier,
    label = tempFreight.carrier_label
  };
  frt_carriers.Add(tempDropDown);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`tempDropDown` is the same object throughout the whole loop. You will need to create a new instance of it if you want to add more than one.

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what exactly your'e trying to do with adding that tempDropDown the the list.

Comment: Yea, I was confused because it wasn't causing a problem with my freights object, but that's because I was getting a new object each iteration from the function readBaseFreight)...

Comment: to be honest, it was not my idea...the list of freights gets returned in JSON (it will be used by an app) and i was told to create a separate list of all possible values for each carrier/mode so that the user could filter the results further (if they want)...to me, it would make sense that the list of unique values would be created by the app...I should just return the list of freights...but...yeah...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is majorly due the shallow copy of list that is created by default. If a deep copy of the list is maintained it will not reflect any change made to it in other references.

For Primitive Types you can do this:

```
List<string> CopyList = new List<string>(OriginalList);
```

For non-primitve/user-difined types you can do this:

```
List<Person> CopyList = new List<Person>();
foreach(var item in OriginalList)
{
     CopyList.Add(new Person { 
        Name = item.Name,
        Address = item.Address
});
}
```