# C# - Items inside a list changing when temp value used to add items changes

Tags: c#, list, loops

I've been trying to add multiple items to a list using a temporary variable and a loop of some kind. I'll create the temp variable and list outside of the loop, and then inside the loop the temp variable will change value, and then will be added to the list as a new element before the loop repeats. The problem is, whenever the temp variable is changed, all elements in the list will change to be the same.

As an example, if I was making a list of fruits, and entered te list 'banana', 'apple' and 'pear', the list when written to the console would read 'pear', 'pear' and 'pear', which is also how the list appears in debugging mode.

The specific code I've been typing is below:

```
string inputText = "";
List<TextNumbers> inputTextChars = new List<TextNumbers>();
TextNumbers temp = new TextNumbers();
bool charFound = false;

inputText = Console.ReadLine();

foreach (char letter in inputText)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < inputTextChars.Count; i++)
    {
        if (letter == inputTextChars.ElementAt(i).character)
        {
            charFound = true;
        }
    }

    if (charFound == false)
    {
        temp.character = letter;
        temp.number = 0;
    }

    temp.number++;
    inputTextChars.Add(temp);

    charFound = false;
}

inputTextChars.Sort();

foreach (TextNumbers text in inputTextChars)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text.character + ": " + text.number);
}
```

The class 'TextNumbers' is:

```
public class TextNumbers
{
    public char character;
    public int number;
}
```

Comment: This is a common error. Move the declaration and initialization of the _temp_ variable inside the loop. Your current code changes the same object instance at each loop and at the end you see only the last change

Comment: yup - its the same temp every time around - make a new one each time instead

Comment: @Steve Thanks, your suggestion works, and I had no idea this was such an easy fix.

Comment: Yes, but you really should try to understand how references works otherwise these kind of errors will be very frequent.

Comment: Try : temp = new TextNumbers(); and then inputTextChars.Add(temp);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as you can see from [the accepted answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275768/list-add-seems-to-be-adding-a-reference-to-the-original-object) :

> Yes, a list of reference types is actually just a list of references

This means you are adding a reference to `temp` to the list every time.

To avoid this, move the declaration of the temp variable to within your loop so that you are adding a reference to a completely new object every time, like so:

```
foreach (char letter in inputText)
{
    TextNumbers temp = new TextNumbers();
    //..... rest of code
```