# How to pass list to wcf?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have class contain Data member:

```
[DataContract]
public class InventoryTransfer
{     
    [DataMember]public List<InventoryTransferLine> Line { get; set; }   
}

[DataContract]
public classInventoryTransferLine
{
    [Data Member(Order = 1)]public string Item Code { get; set; }
    [Data Member(Order = 2)]public Decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

this is client code that i call above wcf service:

```
    T.InsertTransactionClient oClient = new T.InsertTransactionClient();
    T.InventoryTransfer oInventoryTransfer = new T.InventoryTransfer();
    T.InventoryTransferLine oInventoryTransferLine = newT.InventoryTransferLine();

    oInventoryTransfer. Line = new List<T.InventoryTransferLine>();
    oInventoryTransferLine.ItemCode = "1";
    oInventoryTransfer.Line.Add(oInventoryTransferLine);
    oInventoryTransferLine.ItemCode = "2";      
    oInventoryTransfer.Line.Add(oInventoryTransferLine);
    oClient.InventoryTransfer(oInventoryTransfer);
```

so I need the out put:

`oInventoryTransfer.Line[0].ItemCode.ToString();` need output 1 but i got 2.
   `oInventoryTransfer.Line[1].ItemCode.ToString();` out put is 2

Comment: `oInventoryTransferLine.ItemCode = "1";` is replaced by `oInventoryTransferLine.ItemCode = "2";`.   In other words, the second call replaces the value in `ItemCode` with "2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create two separate `T.InventoryTransferLine` instead of updating one after it is inserted.

Inserting an object into a `List` inserts a reference to that object instead of a copy of it.

You should also check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275768/list-add-seems-to-be-adding-a-reference-to-the-original-object).